# Some questions about Memcached and NOSQL

Tags: nosql, memcached

Like many others, I'm thinking about using a NOSQL Database for a new project. Have a few noob questions:

1. If an application uses NOSQL Database like MongoDB or CouchDB, should it still use memcached also, or there won't be any benefit to adding memcached tothe application?
2. Do NOSQL Databases provide Management UI like MS SQL Server Management Studio that allows creating/managing tables and querying/viewing data?
3. For Memcached, can we set Database Expiration dependecies, like we can in .Net Cache, so that the cached item automatically expires if the record is updated in SQL?

Thanks